# How can I test my cron job in localhost windows? (laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, laravel, cron, laravel-5.3, scheduling

I create a cron job on laravel 5.3 by editing app\Console\Kernel.php like this :

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;
use DB;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $id = 1;
            DB::table('orders')
              ->where('id', $id)
              ->update(['status ' => 2, 'canceled_at' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s")]);
        })->everyMinute();
    }

    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

I tried to check on the table in the database, but it does not update

How can I test my cron job?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Run `php artisan list` command in cmd and find your cron.
2. Run `php artisan yourcron`.

You can read [this blog post on our website](http://www.addwebsolution.com/blog/laravel-5-task-scheduler) for more details about cron jobs.

Comment: When I run this : `php artisan yourcron`
It's successful update status = 2. After that I change the status manually again become 1, and then I wait one minute, it does not update status again

Comment: did you add the schedule command on your crontab on the server

Comment: Maybe instead of `php artisan list` you can do `php artisan schedule:list` which will only show the cron / scheduled jobs

Answer (score 6):

Go to the project directory and run

```
php /path/to/artisan schedule:run
```

More info about that: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

hey you can create log file too at the time of defining cron. as i ahve created mine...

```
* * * * * php /var/www/html/sharep/artisan ElasticSearch:ElasticSearchData >> /var/www/html/sharep.log 2>&1
```

this cron run after 1 minute. and the logs saves in .log file as mention above.